# Cassandra 2.2.5 to 3.0.4 upgrade fails

Tags: cassandra, upgrade, datastax

Pretty much what it says.

Quiesce node, stop cassandra, upgrade cassandra RPMs from 2.2.5 to 3.0.4 and then start cassandra. When it comes back up:

```
INFO  13:02:50 Detected version upgrade from 2.2.5 to 3.0.4, snapshotting system keyspace
INFO  13:02:50 Updating topology for all endpoints that have changed
Exception (java.lang.RuntimeException) encountered during startup: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('K' (code 75)): expected a valid value (numbe
r, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@27be81e5; line: 1, column: 2]
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('K' (code 75)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'fals
e' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@27be81e5; line: 1, column: 2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.fromJsonMap(FBUtilities.java:561)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator.decodeTableParams(LegacySchemaMigrator.java:381)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator.decodeTableMetadata(LegacySchemaMigrator.java:363)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator.readTableMetadata(LegacySchemaMigrator.java:273)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator.readTable(LegacySchemaMigrator.java:244)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator.lambda$readTables$233(LegacySchemaMigrator.java:237)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator.readTables(LegacySchemaMigrator.java:237)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator.readKeyspace(LegacySchemaMigrator.java:186)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator.lambda$readSchema$230(LegacySchemaMigrator.java:177)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator.readSchema(LegacySchemaMigrator.java:177)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator.migrate(LegacySchemaMigrator.java:77)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:223)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:551)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:679)
```

And the node dies. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed: delete everything in the datadir/system*/* and make it rebuild.